# Can't Upload Avatar in Ultimate Membership Pro plugin

Tags: wordpress, gravatar, ultimate-member

I have enabled Avatar section in the On Account Page section.
Whenever any user tries to upload an image by clicking, the plugin genrates a modal that covers the whole screen and does not allow to click any other buttons present on screen, all of this while the loading animation is running behind it endlessly.
Please check the images attached

[This modal is coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8zUr.png)

```html
<div id="croppicModalObj" class="ihc-cst-croppic ihc-croppicModalObj" style=" width:250px; height:250px; margin-top:343.5px;"> <img src="imagelink.jpeg"></div>
```

The modal isnt allowing user to click on save changes button

[Added screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcRaJ.jpg)